# can't insert to oracle db using spring boot native method

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g

Below is my piece of a code I'm trying insert in oracle db.I'm using spring boot to insert in the db. When I run the insert process the application hangs on the
  **Integer updateCount = query.executeUpdate();** and nothing is happening.

```
 @Entity
 public class SystemTypeLookup{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected UUID id;


    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    }


Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO system_type_lookup ( id, code) VALUES (:id, :code)");

          query.setParameter("id", dataId.toString());
          query.setParameter("code", code);

          Integer updateCount = query.executeUpdate();
```

**full code using test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {DeploymentTestApplicationConfig.class})
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
    @Transactional
    public class SystemTypeLookupWithQueryTest  {

         @PersistenceContext
         private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Test
        @Rollback(false)
        public void test1_CreateDataTest() {
             UUID id = "397fe5d3-0f44-4ff0-8765-d9c5d24fb9e3";
             String code = "ORG";
             Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO system_type_lookup ( id, code) VALUES (:id, :code)");

              query.setParameter("id", dataId.toString());
              query.setParameter("code", code);

              Integer updateCount = query.executeUpdate();

        }
```

Comment: Post full DAO method with transactions.

Comment: @mallikarjun basically I'm trying to insert it using test case. code updated.